# How to cycle through images on click?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to get an image to cycle through other images (and loop) when clicked (no timing involved). I have it working for one image with this code:

```
<script>
    var NumberOfImages = 2

    var img = new Array(NumberOfImages)

    img[0] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DNISePZjJ4g/U9bSB5NjEzI/AAAAAAAARCw/K7OGOPjQd0Q/s1600/2.png"
    img[1] = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MoL1MHN12Eo/U9bSB6EIS-I/AAAAAAAARCs/gUSKbzsg05g/s1600/3.png"

    var imgNumber = 0

    function NextImage()
    {
        imgNumber++
        if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages)
            imgNumber = 0
        document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
    }
</script>

<A HREF="javascript:NextImage()">
<IMG SRC="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-8ChQ3SBxYOY/U9bSBt4bcMI/AAAAAAAARDE/zLDJ1kP903A/s1600/1.png" name="VCRImage" BORDER=0></A>
```

My problem is that I'm unsure how to place a second image and have it cycle through different images. I've tried duplicating both the JavaScript and HTML and changing the "VCRImage" on the second to another name, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you find this answer helpful, and consider accepting it.

Looking at your code I did a couple modifications to get this running for you. At first they may seem a bit drastic, but if you take the time to understand them you will see the benefits.

- First I removed the Anchor elements. You were using these to simply wireup the click events. A much more preferred way to do this is query for the elements within JavaScript, and bind event listeners to each of them.  By removing the anchors I also lost the pointer when a user hovers over the image, to fix this I added a CSS class that gives the same effect.
- Next I place each image element within a closure function so each image then has access to their own counter variable. When the click event is raised the counter variable while outside the scope of the anonymous function, has access to the captured counter element. Allowing it to freely update it.

I commented the code where there may be confusion. If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

**HTML:**

```
<IMG SRC="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-8ChQ3SBxYOY/U9bSBt4bcMI/AAAAAAAARDE/zLDJ1kP903A/s1600/1.png" name="VCRImage" BORDER=0>

<IMG SRC="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-8ChQ3SBxYOY/U9bSBt4bcMI/AAAAAAAARDE/zLDJ1kP903A/s1600/1.png" name="VCRImage" BORDER=0>
```

**CSS:**

```
img[name=VCRImage]:hover
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    //Declare an image array same as calling new Array();
    var img = []
    img[0] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DNISePZjJ4g/U9bSB5NjEzI/AAAAAAAARCw/K7OGOPjQd0Q/s1600/2.png";
    img[1] = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MoL1MHN12Eo/U9bSB6EIS-I/AAAAAAAARCs/gUSKbzsg05g/s1600/3.png";

    //Select all elements on the page with the name attribute equal to VCRImage
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('[name=VCRImage]');

    //For each image bind the click event
    for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
      var image = images[i];
      //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener
      image.addEventListener('click', imageClicked(), false);
    }

    function imageClicked()
    {
      //Use a closure to wrap the counter variable
      //so each image element has their own unique counter
      var counter = 0;
      return function(event)
      {
        //Increment counter
        counter++;
        //The context of "this" is the image element
        //Use a modulus
        this.src = img[counter % img.length];
      }
    }
```

See it in action here:
http://jsbin.com/veqakame/1/edit

**Update:**
To make the images work off their own alternate image sets I created a data-altimage property on the element.  This attribute's value is set to a comma delimited set of image sources that the image will use when clicked.

http://jsbin.com/qiridote/1/edit

Comment: You'll have to forgive my lack of coding knowledge.

I went ahead and saved myself the CSS by making the "cursor:pointer" a style element. However, I'm having trouble placing your JavaScript into an HTML field. I am placing it within <style> tags, but it quits functioning for some reason.

Comment: I did solve my original issue here, but I'm still wondering how to use multiple of these scripts on one page, as per my original question. Once that is solved, I will be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple of these scripts"?

Comment: Essentially, I just want to have different images (as in your HTML) to be able to perform this cycle function with different sets of images, all on one page. I have tried using this same script four times over and simply swapping out VCRImage, but they all seem to draw from the last script regardless of the names.

Comment: Epic. Can this be used with a swipe left function as seen here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_swipeleft

To move to the next image...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'img.length' to determine the size of the array.
So you don't have to use the NumberOfImages variable.

Like this:

```
var img = new Array()

img[0] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DNISePZjJ4g/U9bSB5NjEzI/AAAAAAAARCw/K7OGOPjQd0Q/s1600/2.png"
img[1] = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MoL1MHN12Eo/U9bSB6EIS-I/AAAAAAAARCs/gUSKbzsg05g/s1600/3.png"

var imgNumber = 0

function NextImage()
{
imgNumber++
if (imgNumber == img.length)
    imgNumber = 0
document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
}
```